# Run a particular script everyday using crontab

Tags: shell, unix

I have cron job which run every day at `4:00 am`

```
00 4 * * * /home/unix/test.sh
```

suppose now time is `1:00 am` and i don't want to run  this cron job only for today 
what i have to do .

Comment: Comment this line, go home to sleep, and uncomment it tomorrow when you at work.

Comment: @nicky_zs, you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @l'L'l, OK, I'll do that.

Comment: The only not-too-brittle solution I can think of is: inside /home/unix/test.sh, add a line like "test -e ~/do_not_run_test.sh && exit"; create/remove that file as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do something like this: remove the job from cron, but first schedule a mechanism to restore it.

```
crontab -l > current.crontab
at now + 4 hours <<END
crontab current.crontab
END
```

Then, edit the crontab and comment out or remove the job you don't want to run today.

Answer (score 1):

Comment the line, go home to sleep, and uncomment it tomorrow when you at work.

```
crontab -e
```

insert # at the beginning of the line you want to stop for a while:

```
# 00 4 * * * /home/unix/test.sh

save and exit
```

Comment: @Maverick, you're welcome. Ha! It's very funny that a "go to sleep" answer works. And, wish you a good night. ^_^

Comment: yes it works well . i 'm new in unix , i got the job months ago ...i need help in bash shell script too if you could , i 'll post more question with possible answers and conclusions .

Comment: yes , sure i 'll ...but for i need minimum 15 points..i joined stackoverflow today only...by the way it's pleasure to meet you

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Make your script non executable:

**Example:**

```
chmod -x /home/unix/test.sh
```

**2)** Make the script executable on 17 July (tomorrow) at 6 a.m. (or whatever, after 4 a.m.)

```
# Make the script executable on 17 July (tomorrow).
0 6 29 7 * chmod +x /home/unix/test.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

That's really not what cron is intended for, but if you knew the day of the week you can change to job to be every day of the week except the current day.  For example if the day was Sunday you could give the range 1-6 (range: 1-7, 1 standing for Monday) so your cron job would look like

00 4 * * * 1-6 /home/unix/test.sh

Good reference for cron format [here](http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm)

After the day was over you could change it back to the original to run every day again.

Or you could just disable cron for this time if you didn't have any other jobs to worry about (sudo /etc/init.d/cron stop) and then enable it again after 4:00am.

You could even just disable cron, and then run a simple bash command to have it enabled in 4 hours.  Example:

First stop cron:
sudo /etc/init.d/cron stop

Then run bash command to seep for 4 hours and then enable cron (you would need to run this as root depending on how you have permissions set for disabling cron):

sleep 4h; /etc/init.d/cron start

Then you could just run those two commands and go back to bed and your cron would be disable for 4 hours and then be enabled for the rest of time! (or until disabled again).  There's other ways, just have to be creative I guess.